# Custom button for onclick event inside form causes redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, button, erb

I have `<button onclick="doSomething();">Do something</button>` inside `form_for` helper. Сlicking on it causes form submission. Instead I want only to do something client-side work for what it is intended.
How can I achieve it?

EDIT: I can use only `<button>` tag for my purposes and it'll be rather well if I could place it inside form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy: just add <del>water</del> **return false;**. See example:

```
<button onclick="doSomething();return false;">Do something</button>
```

I need weekend rest and 5 minutes googling after :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Working method with `<form>`
Make sure your button is written like this: 
`<input type="button" onclick="doSomething()">`

You can select the the form by it's index. So if this is the first `<form>` element on your web page, it's index would be 0. And so on. The index is the order of the elements. If you're having trouble with this, you can always name your form and select it by name. Here's how:

```
var form = document.forms[0]; //selecting by index
var namedForm = document.forms["someForm"]; //Selects <form name="someForm">
var name = form.elements["nameInput"].value; //Selects <input type="text" name="nameInput">
```

And so forth. Let me know if you run into any trouble with this.

Comment: I know for a fact the 2nd paragraph method I posted works. I used to program HTML and JavaScript and used that method. It's probably not the best way to do things when you have a lot of elements to deal with but if you don't have a lot of elements to work with, I'd use it. It gets the job done.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've mixed comments. Yes, it works, but "I need form for other actions and just want place button inside it."

Comment: I figured out a working method by messing around with some HTML code. I managed to get it working. See my edited post above to see how it's done.

Comment: Thank you for help.
I've already have the jquery code working. It works well. The deal is when I click on link, for example `<a onclick="doSomething();">` I have job done without form submission. But when I click on button within form it causes form submission. And notice that I need `<button>` tag instead of `<input type="button">`, because I use twitter bootstrap styled buttons.

Comment: Ah, well I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10064/discussion-between-anthony-and-sergey-alekseev)

Answer (score 0):

`<button onclick="doSomething();void(0)">Do something</button>`

Although it's usually better practice to hook into the button's click event from JavaScript, separating concerns.

Comment: I need form for other actions and just want place button inside it.

Comment: Sorry, I've mixed comments. This approach doesn't work unfortunately.